# Can someone show me how to populate the following MySQL table?

Tags: mysql

Can someone please show me how to pouplate the following table with my own tags, ids and count numbers using the phpMyAdmin or a MySQL command prompt?

```
CREATE TABLE tags (
id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
PRIMARY KEY(id),
tag varchar(100) NOT NULL,
count int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using a SQL reserved word for a column name (unadvisable), you'll need to surround that column name with backticks in your SQL statement. Try this:

```
insert into tags (tag, `count`) values
('java', 14),
('mysql', 3),
('php, 7);
```

the id column will be auto-populated by auto_increment.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
INSERT INTO tags (id, tag, `count`) VALUES (1, 'foo', 1), (2, 'bar', 1);
```